# Update colum with value from another column + text

Tags: dynamic-sql

I imported an e-store's database values into my own, and it mostly worked out fine. However, there were no image file names. So, I need to update the entire database- over 6,000 records, so that under 'image' we get a path + model name + jpg, so each product can be associated with an image. Im having trouble mixing the dynamic column value with the static path. Here is what I need to accomplish:

```
UPDATE `store`.`pr_product` 
SET `image` = 'data/products/`**model_no**`.jpg' 
WHERE `pr_product`.`product_id` = `pr_product`.`product_id` ;
```

But cannot get it to recognize the dynamic nature of 'model_no'

Thanks in advance

Comment: As a general note for any future questions: it would be useful to know **what** database system (and version, edition etc.) you're using - not everything in the SQL language is always the same across all vendors / systems! See great tips on how to ask **good* questions on Stackoverflow: http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Answer (score 1):

Max,

Please what you means about dynamic nature of 'model_no'?
Is this column's datatype int or long or varchar

Please need more explaination with example

you can test the following if  e.g model_no is column in pr_product table

```
UPDATE store.pr_product 
SET image = 'data/products/'+pr_product.model_no+'.jpg' 
WHERE pr_product.product_id = pr_product.product_id ;
```

Best Regards,

Mohammed Thabet Zaky